# Mapping Shift+Arrows to select text in tmux with vim

Tags: linux, windows, vim, tmux

I use vim in linux and have recently started to use tmux too. I use vim with the Windows shortcuts instead of the vim ones, for example; Shift+Arrows for selection instead of HJKL, Shift+Arrows for selecting text, Ctrl+C copy, Ctrl+V paste, Ctrl+Arrows for navigation.

I have had an issue since moving to vim with tmux whereby when I'm in vim while in tmux, I am unable to select text with Shift+Arrows, as this deletes lines. I suspect there's a clash between tmux bindings and Windows shortcuts. This is also the case when I use Ctrl+Arrows. I would want to navigate between words, however this deletes text for some peculiar reason.

Am I able to change anything in my `~/.tmux.conf` that will remove this and allow me to use Shift+Arrows for selection in vim? I am unwilling to change to the conventional vim bindings as of now.

I have also noticed that the same issue is present in GNU screen, so it's not exclusive to tmux.

I suppose what I'm asking is how am I able to get my terminal and vim to function as normal, in a terminal multiplexer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are most likely to be wrong:

1. tmux and the terminal don't agree on what keys like `S-Left` send, so tmux doesn't recognise what the terminal is sending.
2. vim and tmux don't agree on what the keys send, so vim doesn't recognise what tmux is sending.

You can run `cat` and press `S-Left` to see what is being sent.

It is a bit hard to be too specific since you don't mention tmux version, what terminal emulator you are using or what you have `TERM` set to, but:

Inside tmux you should see `^[[1;2D` for `S-Left`. If you don't then probably tmux does not recognise what the terminal is sending and you should:

- Make sure `TERM` is set correctly outside tmux.
- Make sure what you see with `cat` for `S-Left` outside tmux is either `^[[1;2D` or matches the output of `tput kLFT2|cat -v`. If it isn't, you either need a different `TERM` or to override what tmux is expecting for these keys with `terminal-overrides`.

Similarly for `C-Left` except it will be `^[[1;5D` and `kLFT5`. `S-Right` is `kRIT2`, `S-Up` is `kUP2` and `S-Down` is `kDN2`.

If you do see `^[[1;2D` inside tmux then the problem is most likely with vim:

- If you tmux is older than version 2.4, make sure `xterm-keys` is set to on (`set -g xterm-keys on`).
- Make sure `TERM` is set correctly inside tmux - if it is set to `screen`, try `tmux` instead if it is available. You may need to change the `default-terminal` option.
- If that doesn't help, you may need to configure the keys explicitly in your vim config.